# add google analytics code to all pages by nginx

Tags: nginx, google-analytics

I want to add my Google Analytics code to all website pages 
i try to set

```
sub_filter
```

it's not working

```
 set $tracking_id 'UA-12345678-9';
sub_filter '</head>' '<script type="text/javascript">var _gaq=[["_setAccount","$tracking_id"],["_trackPageview"]];(function(d,t){var g=d.createElement(t),s=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];g.async=1;g.src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js";s.parentNode.insertBefore(g,s)})(document,"script")</script></head>';
```

and i try to use

```
add_before_body /file.html
```

it's give me error page not loading

and i try to use

```
add_after_body /file.html
```

it's working good , but it's set code out html of page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

normal nginx can't help you

you will need to install google nginx

PageSpeed Module
that will help you to minify css , html , js , Analytics and more

https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/

to add it to your nginx setup

follow url

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-ngx_pagespeed-to-nginx-on-centos-7